# SSRS Delivery Extension Sample or Tutorial or Example

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, ssrs-2016

For a SQL Server developer wanting to create and implement a [SSRS Delivery Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/extensions/delivery-extension/delivery-extensions-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) needs a good step by step tutorial or example to follow.

However, I can only [find one](https://julientheys.wordpress.com/coding/ssrs-custom-delivery-extension/) and as far as I tell it's either incomplete or not easy for a beginner to follow.

I want to create a Delivery Extension that renders a report in excel, password protect it and then email.

If anyone can point in the direction of others that would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doc has a link to [Implementing a Delivery Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/extensions/delivery-extension/implementing-a-delivery-extension?view=sql-server-ver15), which links to [SQL Server Reporting Services Product Samples](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=msftrsprodsamples), which has all the older SSRS code samples, including a custom delivery extension sample.

Although you might find it *much* easier to just have an external program that fetches an Excel doc through [SSRS URL Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15), and perform the additional delivery actions.  A Delivery Extension is only necessary if you need to extend the SSRS engine to allow users to create subscriptions that use your Delivery method.

Answer (score 1):

The latest samples are now [here on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/Reporting-Services). The "CustomSecuritySample" folder is more recent than the "CustomSecuritySample2016" one.